# Distinct roots of $ \int\limits_0^x {\frac{{{t^2}}}{{1 + {t^4}}}dt} = 2x -1$

Tags: calculus

The total number of distinct $x\in[0,1]$ for which $ \int\limits_0^x {\frac{{{t^2}}}{{1 + {t^4}}}dt}  = 2x -1$ is ________.

My approach is as follow

$y = \int\limits_0^x {\frac{{{t^2}}}{{1 + {t^4}}}dt}  - 2x + 1$

$y' = \frac{{{x^2}}}{{1 + {x^4}}} - 2$

$y' = \frac{1}{{{x^2} + \frac{1}{{{x^2}}}}} - 2$

${x^2} + \frac{1}{{{x^2}}} \ge 2\left( {AM \ge GM} \right)$

Hence $y'<0$ decreasing

$y\left( 0 \right) = \int\limits_0^0 {\frac{{{t^2}}}{{1 + {t^4}}}dt}  - 2 \times 0 + 1 = 1$

The official answer is $1$ but how we will find whether $y(1)<0$

Comment: Argue that $\int\limits_0^\infty {\frac{{{t^2}}}{{1 + {t^4}}}dt}<\infty$ so that $\lim_{x\to\infty}y=-\infty$

Comment: I got $x\approx 0.523$ where the integral is about $0.046$ and $(2x-1)$ too

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore (and Andrew Chin), the OP has done one helpful thing here, not present (as near as I can tell) at the duplicates: they make mention of the AGM inequality, which leads to an easy answer (see mine, below) to the question.

Comment: @saulspatz, the argument you propose only shows there's a root in $(0,\infty)$, not in $(0,1)$.

Comment: @BarryCipra OK but its still a duplicate isn't it,wouldn't it be more appropriate to put your nice answer along with the original one,correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @BarryCipra I misread the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $AM\ge GM$ approach in effect already shows it, just apply it to

$${t^2\over1+t^4}={1\over t^2+{1\over t^2}}\le{1\over2}$$

so

$$y(1)=\int_0^1{t^2\over1+t^4}\,dt-2\cdot1+1\le{1\over2}-2+1=-{1\over2}$$